# SQL: Group by "business days"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to group a search result by days, but unfortunately, the definition is not a day from midnight to midnight (00:00-24:00), but from 06:00 to 06:00.

Any easy solution? If possible in PL-SQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE - 6/24)
```

`- 6/24` subtracts 6 hours from the datetime in the column `DATE` and thus all times between 06:00 and 06:00 will be the same day. `TRUNC` then removes the time part as you only need the date.

Comment: +1. Some solution like the above in which you substruct 6 hours from date

Comment: hm. ok, needed to figure out how to make the solution work. This works for me: `SELECT trunc(DATE-6/24), ID FROM TABLE GROUP BY trunc(DATE-6/24), ID`